# Grabbing columns with special characters and upper case letters

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame and I'm trying to loop through the data frame to identify those columns which contain a special character or which are all capital letters.

I have tried a few things but nothing where I'm apple to catch the column names within the loop.

```
data = data.frame(one=c(1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5), two=c(1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5), 
                thr=c("A","B","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","H","I","J"),
                fou=c("A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D"),
                fiv=c(1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,5), 
                six=c("A","B","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","H","I","J"),
                sev=c("A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D"),
                eig=c("A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D"),
                nin=c(1.24,3.52,5.33,1.44,3.11,5.33,1.55,3.66,5.33,1.32,3.54,5.77),
                ten=c(1:12),
                ele=rep(1,12),
                twe=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2), 
                thir=c("THiS","THAT34","T(&*(", "!!!","@$#","$Q%J","who","THIS","this","this","this","this"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data

colls <- c()

    spec=c("$","%","&")
    for( col in names(data) ) {
      if( length(strings[stringr::str_detect(data[,col], spec)]) >= 1 ){
          print("HORRAY")
colls <- c(collls, col) 
      }
      else print ("NOOOOOOOOOO")
    }


    for( col in names(data) ) {
      if( any(data[,col]) %in% spec ){
        print("HORRAY") 
colls <- c(collls, col)
      }
      else print ("NOOOOOOOOOO")
    }
```

Can anyone shed light on a good way to tackle this problem.

EDIT:

The end goal is to have a vector with a name of column names which meet that criteria. Sorry for my poor SO question, but hopefully this will help with what I'm trying to do

Comment: Is there any point to having the data in columns rather than just as strings (one string per row)?

Comment: That's just how the data is and I'll also have to loop through the logical, numeric, etc columns. I guess that I could extract them and save it as a vector, but at the end of the day, the goal is to get the column name for the variable which contains a special character and so forth

Comment: You usually get better results if you include your "end of the day" goal in your question.

Comment: I have amended  my answer below to to check each column and then return a list of matching column names.

Answer (score 2):

I would use grep() to search for the pattern you are interested in. See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html).

`[:upper:]` Matches any upper case letters.

Combining it with anchors (^,$) and match one or more times (+) gives `^[[:upper:]]+$` and should only match entries completely in capitals.

The following would match the special characters in your toy data set (but is not guaranteed to match all special characters in your real data set i.e form feeds, carriage returns)

`[:punct:]` #Matches punctuation - ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~.

Note that rather than use `[:punct:]` you could define your special characters manually.

We can try the resultant code on the first row of your data set:

```
#Using grepl() rather than grep() so that we return a list of logical values.
grepl(x= data[1,], pattern = "^[[:upper:]]+$|[[:punct:]]")
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This gives us our expected response except for column nine which has the value 1.24.  Here the decimal point is being recognised as punctuation and is being flagged as a match. 
We can add a "negative lookahead assertion" - `(?!\\.)`  -  to remove any periods from consideration, before they are even tested for being punctuation characters. Note we use \ to escape the period.

```
grepl(x= data[1,], perl = TRUE, pattern = "(?!\\.)(^[[:upper:]]+$|[[:punct:]])")
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

This returns a better response - it now no longer matches decimal places. NOTE: This might not be what you want as this pattern also won't match any fullstops in character fields.  You would need to refine the pattern further.

Rather than use a 'for loop' to reiterate this code across every row in your dataframe I would use vectorization instead which is 'more R like'.

To do this we must convert our script into a function which we will call with apply()

```
myFunction <- function(x){
      matches <- grepl(x= x, perl = TRUE, pattern = "(?!\\.)(^[[:upper:]]+$|[[:punct:]])")
  #Given a set of logical vectors 'matches', is at least one of the values true? using any()
  return(any(matches))
}

apply(X = data, 1, myFunction)
```

The 1 above instructs apply() to reiterate across rows rather than columns.

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In your example data set all rows have an entry containing a special character or a string of all capital letters.  This is unsurprising as many columns in your example data set are a list of single capital letters.

If you are just interested in which values in column thirteen fit the stated criteria you can use:

```
matches <- grepl(x= data$thir, perl = TRUE, pattern = "(?!\\.)(^[[:upper:]]+$|[[:punct:]])")
matches
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

To subset your dataframe on matching rows:

```
data[matches,]
  one two thr fou fiv six sev eig  nin ten ele twe  thir
3   5   5   D   D   5   D   D   D 5.33   3   1   1 T(&*(
4   1   1   E   A   1   E   A   A 1.44   4   1   2   !!!
5   3   3   F   B   3   F   B   B 3.11   5   1   1   @$#
6   5   5   G   D   5   G   D   D 5.33   6   1   2  $Q%J
8   3   3   I   B   3   I   B   B 3.66   8   1   2  THIS
```

To subset your dataframe on non-matching rows:

```
data[!matches,]
   one two thr fou fiv six sev eig  nin ten ele twe   thir
1    1   1   A   A   1   A   A   A 1.24   1   1   1   THiS
2    3   3   B   B   3   B   B   B 3.52   2   1   2 THAT34
7    1   1   H   A   1   H   A   A 1.55   7   1   1    who
9    5   5   J   D   5   J   D   D 5.33   9   1   1   this
10   1   1   H   A   1   H   A   A 1.32  10   1   2   this
11   3   3   I   B   3   I   B   B 3.54  11   1   1   this
12   5   5   J   D   5   J   D   D 5.77  12   1   2   this
```

Note that the regular expression used doesn't match THAT34 as it isn't composed wholly of capitalised letters, having the number 34 at the end.

EDIT:

To get a list of column names identifying columns that fulfill the criteria in your edit use `myFunction` described above with:

```
colnames(data)[apply(X = data, 2, myFunction)]
"thr"  "fou"  "six"  "sev"  "eig"  "thir"
```

The number in apply() changes from 1 to 2 to reiterate across columns rather than rows.  We pass the output from apply(), a list of logical matches (TRUE or FALSE), to colnames(data) - this returns the matching column names via subsetting.

Answer (score 1):

I would collapse the data into strings (one string per row)

```
strings = apply(data, 1, paste, collapse = "")
contains_only_caps = strings == toupper(strings)
strings[contains_only_caps]
# [1] "33BB3BBB3.52 212THAT34" "55DD5DDD5.33 311T(&*("  "11EA1EAA1.44 412!!!"   "33FB3FBB3.11 511@$#"   
# [5] "55GD5GDD5.33 612$Q%J"   "33IB3IBB3.66 812THIS"  


# escaping special characters
spec=c("\\$","%","\\&")
contains_spec = stringr::str_detect(strings, pattern = paste(spec, collapse = "|"))

strings[contains_spec]
# [1] "55DD5DDD5.33 311T(&*(" "33FB3FBB3.11 511@$#"   "55GD5GDD5.33 612$Q%J"
```

You could also use `which` on `contains_spec` or `contains_only_caps` to get the corresponding row numbers for the original data frame. I think that using strings rather than row-wise data frame elements will by much faster - as long as you want to search the whole strings, not certain columns for certain conditions.